# Join Files with common columns in Python

Tags: python, sorting, join, merge

I have a problem joining two large files with 5 common columns and returning the results, which are the identical 5 tuples...
Here is what I exactly mean:

**File1:**

```
132.227 49202 107.21 80
132.227 49202 107.21 80
132.227 49200 107.220 80
132.227 49200 107.220 80
132.227 49222 207.171 80
132.227 49339 184.730 80
132.227 49291 930.184 80
............
............
............
```

The file contains a lot of lines not just those...

**File 2:**

```
46.109498000 132.227 49200 107.220 80 17 48 
46.927339000 132.227 49291 930.184 80 17 48 
47.422919000 253.123 1985 224.300 1985 17 48
48.412761000 132.253 1985 224.078 1985 17 48
48.638454000 132.127 1985 232.123 1985 17 48
48.909658000 132.227 49291 930.184 80 17 65
48.911360000 132.227 49200 107.220 80 17 231
............
............
............
```

Output File:

```
46.109498000 132.227 49200 107.220 80 17 48 
46.927339000 132.227 49291 930.184 80 17 48 
48.909658000 132.227 49291 930.184 80 17 65
48.911360000 132.227 49200 107.220 80 17 231
............
............
............
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
with open('log1', 'r') as fl1:
    f1 = [i.split(' ') for i in fl1.read().split('\n')]

with open('log2', 'r') as fl2:
    f2 = [i.split(' ') for i in fl2.read().split('\n')]

def merging(x,y):
    list=[]
    for i in x:
        for j in range(len(i)-1):
            while i[j]==[a[b] for a in y]:
                list.append(i)
                j=j+1
    return list

f3=merging(f1,f2)

for i in f3:
    print i
```

Comment: @mskimm , yeah the 2nd file is ordered by the 1st column (it s the start time)

Comment: m Sorry I couldnt add another comm there so I ll rite it here
the 'python --version' is  _Python 2.7.6_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's **file2** is filtered by **file1**. Right?

I assume that the **file1** is not ordered. (If it's ordered, there is another efficient solution)

```
with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2:
    my_filter = [line.strip().split() for line in file1]
    f3 = [line.strip() for line in filter(lambda x: x.strip().split()[1:5] in my_filter, file2)]

# to see f3
for line in f3:
    print line
```

First, build filter `my_filter = [line.strip().split() for line in file1]` which contains

```
[['132.227', '49202', '107.21', '80'], ['132.227', '49202', '107.21', '80'], ['132.227', '49200', '107.220', '80'], ['132.227', '49200', '107.220', '80'], ['132.227', '49222', '207.171', '80'], ['132.227', '49339', '184.730', '80'], ['132.227', '49291', '930.184', '80']]
```

then using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), filter the data. This code works on **Python 2.7 +**

Comment: yes I have to filter the 2nd file by the first then return the 1st one format (columns)

Comment: Sorry I just saw the other Qst, No file1 isnt ordered, i wasnt sure if i ve to order it, since the file2 is ordered by the 1st column (which doesnt exist in file1)

Comment: I have Python 2.7 on my mac, n still when i try to print the outpu 
(for i in f3: print i) I get nothing... it s empty :(

Comment: did I mention that both files contains thousands of lines (1000 in file1 and about 30000 line in file2 that s why i want to filter)

Comment: The format of data can vary. please provide your data as **a file** for better answer.

Comment: file1:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxb737EB0pVQZGNyZktjVEViMG8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: file2:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxb737EB0pVQU2VwNXFDXzZjS2c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The code I wrote is working on your data. `f3` contains the filtered data. What' the problem?

Comment: srsly!! I tried to print it like thiS:(for i in f3: print i) I got nothing!! :(
I even tried to load it in another file like this:
(for i in f":
  OUTfile.write("%s\n" % i))
it returns nothing!! I dont understand why!!

Comment: Could you tell me how did you get sure the data is in f3??
Thaaaaaaaaaanks

Comment: save the code to `filtering.py`. put `file1` and `file2` to the same directory of `filtering.py`. then run `python filtering.py`. It works on `python 2.7.6`

Comment: thats exactly what i m doin :(

Comment: please share the result of `python --version`

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeesss! now it s working!!
Thanks a loooooooot

the version is 2.7.6 too like yours
I didnt understand what s goin on, I just re-wrote the code and executed it then it worked like magic x)

Comment: Can I ask you for another help??

Comment: Post another question on SO!. Friends will help you!

Comment: it s about th same files... i want th lines left in file2 after this filter
I already had them with my code that I posted bellow by changin if ... to if i[x+1]!=j[x] or ....
but I like your methode it s much better

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this lines and they seem working:

```
with open('file1', 'r') as fl1:
    f1 = [i.split(' ') for i in fl1.read().split('\n')]

with open('file2', 'r') as fl2:
    f2 = [i.split(' ') for i in fl2.read().split('\n')]

for i in f2:
    for j in f1:
        if i[1]==j[0] and i[2]==j[1] and i[3]==j[2] and i[4]==j[3]:
            print i
```

I tried to replace

```
if i[1]==j[0] and i[2]==j[1] and i[3]==j[2] and i[4]==j[3]:
```

with:

```
for k in range(4):
    if i[k+1]==j[k]:
        print i
```

but it gave me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "MERGE.py", line 10, in
>   
>       if i[k+1]==j[k]: IndexError: list index out of range